# how to return the current inserted model as object using model events?

Tags: laravel, events, model, eloquent

I'm inserting tag row in (tags table) as following :

```
$tag = new App\Tag();

$tag->name = 'cars';

$result = $tag->save();
```

**hint :** i want to return the inserted model as object using (model events)

, i stored the code in AppserviceProvider-boot method like this :

```
public function boot() { 

Tag::creating (function ($model) {

     return $model;

    });
```

**But :** i have "true" in return ,,, i can dd() the model but can't return it .

**My question :** how to return the inserted model and ... to store it in the $result variable ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `$tag->save()` it will update the `$tag` with the updated values and if you want to get the `id` then you can access it as:

```
$tag->save();

dd($tag->id);
```

Comment: it's working ... thanks :) it's so simple ,,, you means there is no need for return it using the (model events) !! @Amit Gupta

Comment: Yes, you don't need to use model events for this.

Comment: it's my pleasure ... :) to do that  @Amit Gupta